# Mathematical Induction Discrete

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Use mathematical induction to prove that for every $n > 1$, if a set has $n$ elements, then its power set has $2^n$ elements.

How would I go about solving this, I am totally lost?

Comment: Every subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n,n+1\}$ either includes $(n+1)$ as an element or it doesn't include $(n+1)$ as an element.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematical induction works as follows.

Step I: check the proposition for a small value of $n$, this is usually called the "base case"

Step II: assume that the proposition holds for $n=k$

Step III: using the fact the proposition is true for $n=k$ prove that it is true for $n=k+1$

and you are done!

Hope this helped